# How to transfer Information from one file to another

Tags: excel, vba

I need to transfer information from one file to another.

The file from which the information comes:
[image]

The information I need is from columns D (RTO021,RTO022,etc.), column O (28000, 2000,etc) and the date from the merged cells G to N (07/06/2020).

The macro should place this information into a file with the below aspect:
[image]

Columns "Fact Type", "Unit", "Market" and "Date" should have always the same value and the ones containing "Product", and "Value" should change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you would like to copy information from one workbook to an other. You have to define the source range and the target range. Then you can use the following command.

```
rngTarge.Value = rngSource.Value
```

It is important to have a correct reference to the ranges, like in this example. The name of the workbooks are Target and Source and similarly the name of the worksheets are Target and Source.

```
Sub CopySomething()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarge As Range
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Target.xlsm") 'Set the workbooks
    Set wbSource = Workbooks("Source.xlsm")
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Source") ' Set the worksheets as they are in the workbooks
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Target")
    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A1:A5")  ' Set the ranges as they are in the sheets
    Set rngTarge = wsTarget.Range("A1:A5")
    ' assign the values
    rngTarge.Value = rngSource.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Viktor!! I will try an let you know if it work! Thanks a mill mate :)